# Get the openstack cinder volume size through python bindings

Tags: python-2.7, openstack

Can any one help me out to get the openstack cinder volume size through python bindings.

I have list of cinder volumes that are extracted by calling cinder_client_instance.volumes.list() method.

Now I want to know the size of the volume. How I can get the volume size?

Answer (score 0):

Use the size parameter on volume object.

For example:

for vol in cinder_instance.volume.list():print vol.id    # Gives the cinder volume ID print vol.size  # Gives cinder volume size